# In Malaysia, can someone become a LAME through self study rather than training school?

Tags: pilot-certification, malaysia

Is it possible for someone to self study (without attending a training school) and individually sit for the exams required in order to become a B1 or B2 LAME in Malaysia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to become a licensed AME in Malaysia entirely through self-study. It takes between two and seven years to become licensed as an AME in Malaysia, and that includes two years of practical/on-the-job training at a Malaysian aviation facility/company. You could, in theory, study the theoretical material and try to pass the test, but if you don't go through a Part 147 training program it will take much longer to become licensed.